# Hibernate and SQL Server startup slow

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

Our application uses hibernate3 with SQL Server 2005 server platform. Hibernate configured to update DB structure on startup (hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property to update).

Since last week a problem raised that application starts very slow. Also if to check DB there are no all the necessary indexes which should be created by hibernate.

If to set  hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to validate application starts fast but it is not a solution such as we often change data structure (application is in development). `DBCC CHECKDB` for the database gives no warnings. Also hibernate doesn't report any errors.

If to restore previous database version of one week ago the problem disappears. Application starts fast but I still don't see all the necessary indexes. Also we have a lot of new data since that date entered and don't want to loose it. How to find the cause of so strange behaviour? What can be corrupted in the DB that doesn't allow to create all the indexes.

UPD.: After updating of hibernate to newer version indexes problem disappeared. But startup is still slow. In the log i see that slowest part is table meta data validation by hibernate. What can be the cause?

Comment: What changed in the DB between these dates? was only data added?

Comment: yes, only data was added. Interesting thing i've installed that backup to SQL server 2008 and there all works fine.